# What can I do to expose a standard C++ object in visual C++?

Tags: c#, c++, ios, visual-c++, uwp

I'm writing a universal runtime component using code from a shared standard C++ library (i.e. I can't public ref the whole thing). We want to use this code acress iOS an UWP/Windows Store btw.

The problem is it seems in order to use C++ in my C# uwp app I have to create a universal runtime component using visual C++. I get the incentive of allowing these components to be used by many languages. But how do I expose a basic C++ object to C# in one of these components?

Do I just create an interface and methods for everything I want to expose in visual C++?

Comment: Using [tag:c++-cli] seems to be the easiest option.

Comment: Could you explain? I still get the impression that I have to write a wrapper in order to expose it to C#. I get CLI will be common, but does my C++ code stay standard in that way?

Comment: _"but does my C++ code stay standard in that way?"_ Of course not. Do you have to write portable c++ code?

Comment: Yes I have to write portable C++ code to support UWP and iOS.

Comment: That requires you need to write some extra layer to wrap the plain standard C++ API. C# cannot consume from the native C++ interfaces directly.

Comment: That stinks... That kind of defeats the purpose of portable C++ code. At least for data models (large amounts of members etc..)

Comment: You probably misunderstood what I meant. The c++ kernel API will still be portable. The extra efforts on top is to write a relatively thin layer (well, still easiest using c++-cli) to make the proper marshalling from c++ to c# happen.

Comment: Yeah but doesn't that mean I have to redefine all my class members in the c++cli/clr wrapper? i.e. I can't just say hay here is an object called `bob`. I have to say here is an object called `bob` and his `birthday`, `socialsec`, `bankacct` etc. right?

Comment: Sure, that's what's needed to be done. Who ever promised that C# types should be compatible with native C++?

Comment: At least the primitive types and some of the basics like map or vector. I guess I'll just build it out. But it's unfortunate that it's almost duplicated work at that point.

Comment: If you want a truly portable library, you could also wrap it in a C interface. You'd then make a C# wrapper around that using standard interop (and in this case there'd be no point in using C++/CLI).